# How to match a url link and open it, otherwise google search it?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

i want to mark a bookmarklet which can match my enter words.

if enter words are url like http://,

then open it,

otherwish use google to search it!

here is my code below, but it seems not working!!

```
javascript:var x=prompt('Enter url or text!','');
  let url = x;
  try {
    var reg = /^http[s]?:\/\/(www\.)?(.*)?\/?(.)*/;
    if (!reg.test(url)) {
      url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(url);
    }
    else {
      if (url.substring(4, 0).toLowerCase() == "http") {
        url = encodeURIComponent(url);
      }
      else {
        url = 'http://' + encodeURIComponent(url);
      }
    }
  };
```

use bookmarklet way!

Comment: Please go read [ask]. "Not working" is not a _helpful_ problem description. Give an example of your actual input data, explain what you expect to happen based on that, and what happens instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine, except it fails to match on URLs like `www.stackoverflow.com` (without the `http[s]`) and also it's encoding the forward slashes when `http[s]` is provided.

- Change regex to also match `www.stackoverflow.com`
- Change `encodeURIComponent` to `encodeURI` for URLs that already have `http[s]`.
- Wrap code in [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to avoid redeclaration of variables so it can be called more than once.

**Note:**  This solution won't work for urls such as `stackoverflow.com` which are missing both the `www.` and `http[s].` prefixes.

```js
javascript:(function() {
  var x=prompt('Enter url or text!','');
  let url = x;
  try {
      var reg = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})/;
      if (!reg.test(url)) {
          url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(url);
      } else {
          if (url.substring(4, 0).toLowerCase() == "http") {
              url = encodeURI(url);
          }
          else {
              url = 'http://' + encodeURIComponent(url);
          }
      }
      window.location.href = url;
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: thanks for your kindly reply, can you please make it into bookmarklet? i just did that, but nothing happen when i click it.

Comment: The regex was missing a semicolon (needed because it's interpreted as on one line), which has since been fixed.  Note, in my testing, Chrome won't `prompt(...)`, but Firefox will.

Comment: the bookmarklet seems like only work once, when you click the bookmarklet again, there are nothing happen, but it so close to the answer!

Comment: Consider adding `console.log(err)` to the catch block and checking your browser's console for errors.

Comment: it shows 'Uncaught SyntaxError: redeclaration of let url' when i add console.log

Comment: Right, because you can't declare a variable twice.  Probably needs to be changed to an IIFE to prevent this.

Comment: could you please send me some topics related to this post? it's so colse to the answer!!! but thanks all the same.

Comment: Normal: `javascript:alert('hello');`
IIFE: `javascript:(function(){alert("hello");})();`

Comment: I've updated the code to use IIFE.

Comment: I've added a link to Mozilla's IIFE documentation in the answer as well.  Slight correction: My previous comment about Chrome not working was wrong, the code is working in Firefox as well as Chrome.

Comment: thanks for your kindly reply, you helped me a lot, Many thanks!

Comment: Great.  If you found the solution acceptable, please mark as accepted.